# Get Java compliance level information from command line

Tags: java, command-line, version

I use Java 14 and I want to write a auto configuration script for Eclipse in case I update Java on my machine. Eclipse uses the following line to specify the default Java VM:

`<vmSettings defaultVM="57,org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType13,1597823290779" defaultVMConnector="">`

As you can see, the first parameter in the "defaultVM" attribute is the compliance level and I have no idea on how to get this value (in this case "57") from the java command. "java --version" gives me only "14.0.2" but this is not the compliance level. Is there some other parameter on how to get the compliance level on command line? I would then parse and evaluate it with PowerShell commands. Other commands like "javac" are also usable because I am installing OpenJDK from the zip redist package.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java -XshowSettings:all` will show all available values.  `java -X` will show the available options.  That said, you'll still need to do some translation.  It looks like "compliance level" may correspond to `java.class.version` (major) version:

```sh
$ $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 13)/bin/java -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | grep java.class.version
    java.class.version = 57.0
$ $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 14)/bin/java -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | grep java.class.version
    java.class.version = 58.0
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. Now I can do some line based parsing and I'm done. Thanks a lot!